# Showing this scheduling problem is NP-hard

Tags: reductions, scheduling

I've been reading up on scheduling problems and the class of them that is NP-complete. Specifically, [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X94901422) is a foundational text on such problems, but the reductions are not clear to me. Can someone help identify the reduction from 3-partition, if I am trying to show the problem is NP-hard when I am scheduling tasks on $m$ processors, with precedence constraints on a DAG, and $e(v)$ execution requirement.

Comment: What's the role of the execution requirement $e(v)$? Is it just the time that job $v$ takes to complete? Is the goal that of finding a schedule such all jobs have completed execution by time $D$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is strongly NP-Hard as it can be seen by reducing from the [$3$-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) problem:
given a set $X = \{ x_1,\dots,x_{3n} \}$ of $3n$ positive integers, is there a partition of $X$ into $n$ sets $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ such that (i) the sum of the elements in each set $X_i$ is exactly $T=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{3n} x_i$, and (ii) each set $X_i$ has size $3$?

This problem remains NP-Hard even if every $x_i$ is in the open interval $(T/4, T/2)$, which makes condition (ii) redundant.

Given an instance of 3-partition with every $x_i \in (T/4, T/2)$, you can build an instance of your problem as follows:

- There are $m=n$ processors.
- Each $x_i$ corresponds to a job $v_i$ with $e(v_i) = x_i$ and $\pi(v_i) = \{1, \dots, m\}$ (i.e., the job can be assigned to any processor).
- The deadline $D$ is equal to $T$.
- The graph is $(\{v_1, \dots, v_{3n} \}, \emptyset)$, i.e., there are no edges (jobs can be executed in any order).

If there is a solution $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to the 3-partition instance you can get a feasible scheduling by assigning the jobs corresponding to the $3$ integers in the generic set $X_i$ to processor $i$.

If there is a feasible scheduling, you can get a solution $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to the 3-partition instance by choosing $X_i = \{ x_j, x_k, x_\ell \}$ where $v_j, v_k, v_\ell$ are the jobs assigned to processor $i$ (notice that each processor must have exactly $3$ jobs assigned since any $4$ jobs would exceed $D$, and less than $3$ jobs imply the existence of a processor with more than $3$ jobs).